# Manipulating Strings and its characters in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public static int findFreqWithMutations(String toFind, String[] list) {
    int count = 0;
    String mutation = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        //if there's a mutation, let's change it!
        for (int j = 1; j < list[i].length(); j++) {
            if (list[i].charAt(j - 1) == list[i].charAt(j)) {
                mutation += "";
            } else {
                mutation += list[i].charAt(j - 1);
            }
        }
        //list[i] = mutation + list[i].charAt(list[i].length() - 1);
        mutation += list[i].charAt(list[i].length() - 1);
        list[i] = mutation;
    }
}
```

The code `findFreqWithMutations(String to Find, String [] list)` serves the purpose of scanning through a String array, `String[] list = {"AAA", "ABC", "CDEE", "FGHH"}`, and correcting **mutations** (mutations as in same character consecutively, so `AAA` would be `A` without mutation, and `CDEE` would be `CDE` without mutation).

My third last row: `list[i] = mutation + list[i].charAt(list[i].length() - 1)` work the way it should,

But **NOT** my last two lines of code..

Are they not the same?

Comment: You may want to read documentation about `+=` in Java. (Side note - please try to format code as if anyone would read it - aligning with spaces matter for people).

Comment: *My* first question is: What is the purpose of the `toFind` parameter, since you never use it?

Comment: I think you should initialize the `mutation` variable inside the `i` loop, before the `j` loop, and you should remove the line `mutation += ""` since it doesn't do anything, except waste CPU cycles.

Comment: x += 20 is the equivalent of x = x + 20 so far as I know. toFind comes in after we get rid of all the mutations, we're comparing String toFind with entries that mutation-free.

Comment: @Andreas You were right! Having mutation variable inside the i-loop fixed it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Because you need to clear it when you loop around to process `list[1]`. Try changing the code back, then **debug** to see what went wrong when processing `list[1]`, `list[2]`, ...

Comment: Move ```String mutation = "";``` after the first ```for``` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes, and the result is what you want:

- re-initialize mutation for each string
- test Char (j+1), then keep it
- then finally, nothing to do

  String[] list = {"AAA", "ABC", "CDEE", "FGHH"};

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      {
      // MORE CLEAR
      String source= list[i];
      // PUT INSIDE
      String mutation = "";

      if (source.length()==0) continue; // if void
       mutation+=source.charAt(0);

      //if there's a mutation, let's change it!
      for (int j = 1; j <source.length(); j++)
          {
          if (source.charAt(j - 1) == source.charAt(j))
              mutation += "";
          else 
              mutation += source.charAt(j); // Take this, not the precedent
           }

      list[i] = mutation;
  }
  ```